# Como limpar a query string depois que eu ja peguei os valores que eu quero?

Tags: c#, asp.net, querystring

Estou usando asp.net c#, e queria limpar a query string para que não fique a vista para o usuário, por exemplo "http://meusite.com.br/Pagina1.aspx?parametro=Lucas"..... Eu pego esse nome e uso no meu código quando no pageLoad, mas gostaria que depois que eu pegasse o nome dele, ele não ficasse visível ao usuário.

Comment: Se não der para redirecionar depois de usar a variável, não tem como. Se der, coloco como resposta.

Comment: Olá, pelo que eu vi neste [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page/3354511#3354511) é possível sim usando a função  `window.history.pushState`, existe tb este [artigo](http://spoiledmilk.com/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page/)

Comment: Lucas, tenta usar uma URL amigável.
Tem um link que mostra como fazer isso. http://www.devmedia.com.br/conceitos-e-exemplo-url-amigaveis-em-asp-net/23270

Comment: deu certo a URL amigável, obrigado !

Comment: Você usa esse parametro pra que mesmo?

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

use seguinte código JavaScript

```
//pega a url atual, remove o query string e altera a url
var pageObj = {"html":"","pageTitle":""};
window.history.pushState(pageObj ,"", window.location.href.split('?')[0]);
```

a url é o último parâmetro, e deixei definida por

```
window.location.href.split('?')[0]
```

O objeto passado no primeiro parâmetro pode ter os seguintes itens

execute isto depois de guardar (ou inclua na saída depois de pegar os dados no C#)

[Fonte](http://Fontes:%20[1](http://spoiledmilk.com/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page/)%20e)

Comment: Isso irá causar um redirect na pagina, certo?